# Pytest intermittenty failing using multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, pytest

I have the following function:

```
def parallel_ping(ip_addresses, deadline=1.0, interval=None, attempts=None, pool_size=20):
    try:
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=pool_size)
        args = ((ip, deadline, interval, attempts) for ip in ip_addresses)
        result = pool.map_async(ping_check, args)
        return result.get()
    finally:
        pool.close()
```

ping_check is a function that actually pings the devices (ip_addresses)

in my test, I have mocked out the ping_check function (replaced it with a function that returns the packet_loss).

sometimes when the test runs it raises an exception:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pool' referenced before assignment
```

My test function is inside a test_class that inherits from unittest.TestCase, and has a

```
def setUp(self):
    self.old_function = ping_check
```

and a

```
def tearDown(self):
    ping_check = self.old_function
```

function.

In the test function, I am assigning ping_check = mock_ping_check
and then calling the parallel_ping function in there.

I am not sure why this exception is raised sometimes, and not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is raised when your `ThreadPool(processes=pool_size)` fails. When that happens, an exception is raised instead of the pool being created, which means the `pool` variable is never assigned.

The `finally` block is then immediately executed, and tries to call `pool.close()`, which, since `pool` was never assigned, raises `UnboundLocalError`.

Move your `pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)` line out of the `try` block. It will have the added benefit of telling you exactly *why* the line fails.

Comment: I was looking for an exception that was raised on the pool creation. However, the exception that occurs in the finally block masks that first exception and stack trace.

    try: 
        0/0
    finally:
        1/0

raises an exception on the finally block. Interesting.

Comment: One question, why would the ThreadPool(processes=pool_size) fail intermittently?

Comment: Could be that you're trying to build a pool with either too few or too many processes? Try rerunning your tests until they fail, the traceback will give you the answer now that it's no longer hidden by the finally problem.